# Polymer dom-if: how do I implement a negative condition?

Tags: polymer, dom-if

I have a Polymer element that uses `<template is="dom-if"...` to provide different HTML content depending on a condition.

Polymer `dom-if` has no else condition, so needs a negative if condition to simulate it.

Something like this:

```html
<link href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="test-thing">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{title}}" restamp>
      <b>[[title]]</b>
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!title}}" restamp>
      <i>no title</i>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'test-thing',
      properties: {
        title: String
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<div>
  With negative condition:
  <test-thing></test-thing>
</div>
<div>
  With positive condition:
  <test-thing title="Has Title"></test-thing>
</div>
```

Only that doesn't work - the negative condition never passes.

How should this be implemented?

Comment: Your code must work if title property has no value. Which polymer version are you using?

Comment: @MojtabaSafaeian 1.0 try running that snippet in Chrome 55 - it doesn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanwtyler/6g16qknL/#&togetherjs=w0neSat7uN

Comment: @RyanTyler Could you format that as an answer rather than an external fiddle? The snippet embedded in the question shows the problem and you can copy it to an answer directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use a default empty value for your title property:

```
  title:{type: String,value:''}
```

Like so:

```html
<link href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="test-thing">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{title}}" restamp>
      <b>[[title]]</b>
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!title}}" restamp>
      <i>no title</i>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'test-thing',
      properties: {
        title: {type: String,value:''}
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<div>
  With negative condition:
  <test-thing></test-thing>
</div>
<div>
  With positive condition:
  <test-thing title="Has Title"></test-thing>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, that works (+1 and ans). Any idea why it is required? Surely without a default an unspecified title is `undefined`, which is still falsey.

Comment: Polymer doesn't render expressions with not-yet-set variables. Computed properties also work this way. [Read more](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#simple-observers).